# Why does Eclipse keep deleting my R files, how do I fix

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I closed eclipse one day, all my android apps worked fine. Today I opened them and none of them would work because the R file was gone. When I made a new project, R files were not generated. Cleaning and building would not work either.

Comment: Is your Android SDK up to date?

Comment: clean your project and remove all `import android.R` in your classes, then check for errors in `layouts` XMLs

Comment: There's probably some error in some xml file or there's some resource file containing **invalid characters** in its name.

Comment: What @DerGolem said. If one of your XML's is invalid, then the R file will fail to generate. These XML errors are not always apparent in the Problems view, so you may have to look at the raw AAPT output in the console.